# Wix: single MSI instead of msi + cab

Tags: wix, windows-installer

My Wix project creates install.msi and cab1.cab. How can I have it bundle everything into the msi? I will likely use 7-zip SFX to work around this but I have seen other apps with only a single msi.

Answer (score 277, accepted):

You didn't post any source but I assume your wxs file has a Media element. Just set the EmbedCab attribute to "yes" in `MediaTemplate` e.g.

```
<MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />
```

Comment: I had an empty MediaTemplate element but I replaced it with this:

<Media Id="1" Cabinet="Cab1.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />

Thanks!

Comment: Note, you can add `EmbedCab="yes"` to the `MediaTemplate` element to achieve this.

Comment: MediaTemplate wasn't available until WiX 3.6. wtjones didn't mention what version of WiX he was using so I mentioned the way that would work for more people.

Answer (score 74):

Set `EmbedCab="yes"`.

Since WIX 3.8:

```
<MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />
```

Before WIX 3.8:

```
<Media Id="1" Cabinet="cab1.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />
```

Answer (score 26):

Use it like this :

```
<Media Id="1" Cabinet="CabFileName.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />
```

Also [this](http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/embed-cab-file-msi) article describes other ways of doing it.

Answer (score 8):

With **WiX toolset v4** you just need to add the following `MediaTemplate` element inside your `Package` element:

```xml
<MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />
```

Comment: I'm doing exactly that, and I'm using Wix v4, but it's still not packaging the cab file into the msi.  I can't see why the default behavior would be to leave it hanging outside the installer file. But I guess I can live with it that way if I have to.