# Harvest(Heat) Wix - archive resources in the msi

Tags: c++, visual-studio, wix, windows-installer, heat

Is it possible to archive resources in msi file instead of creating .cab . What is the pros and cons of these two method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Embed Cabs***: If you are referring to eliminating the **`external cab`** during **`MSI compilation`** for **`WiX visual studio projects`**, then you can achieve this by setting the **`EmbedCab attribute`** of the [`MediaTemplate element`](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/mediatemplate.html) to **`"yes"`**:

```
<MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />
```

[**Here is an attempted "minimal changes" sample**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47970743/wix-installer-msi-not-installing-the-winform-app-created-with-visual-studio-2017/47972615#47972615) for how to build a basic MSI after creating a **`WiX project in Visual Studio`**. Suggest scrolling down to the actual WiX markup for the inline comments.

***Why use External Cabs?***: I rarely use external cabs if I can help it, but there are some advantages in some cases centering around **`build-speed`** and more **`reliable downloading`** (according to Arnson, see second link below). There may be further benefits. For example downloading a smaller cab for MSI repair operations if installation source is on a remote server - related to downloading. Cab files can make security software and anti-virus go spastic though.

- [How To: Optimize build speed](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/general/optimizing_builds.html)
- [WiX and cabinetry](https://www.joyofsetup.com/2011/06/21/wix-and-cabinetry/)

---

This question has been answered before BTW - in similar incarnations. See below.

---

***Some Links***:

- [Wix: single MSI instead of msi + cab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284625/wix-single-msi-instead-of-msi-cab)
- For the record: [The embed cab behavior changed in WiX 3.8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40212018/129130)
- [What is the difference between Media and MediaTemplate in WIX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27439643/what-is-the-difference-between-media-and-mediatemplate-in-wix)